# Routing requests to my local domain's www to an external www server using bind

Tags: dns, bind, virtual-host

**Goal**

I want to get my web browser to display the contents of the page at http://www.google.com when I navigate to http://www.domain.tld (leaving the latter in the browser address bar after loading).

**What I've attempted**

I'm a `bind` newbie trying to set up a local domain (say domain.tld).

In my zone file I tried adding the following records but get various errors like 404, unreachable, serverfail:

```
# doesn't work
www IN CNAME www.google.com.
www2 IN A www.google.com
```

When I route to web servers on my LAN, A records work fine:

```
# works
www IN A 192.168.1.2
nuc IN A 192.168.1.3
```

**Question**

Either my DNS configuration is incorrect/incomplete or my understanding of DNS servers is lacking something crucial. Where am I wrong?

**Additional information**

Contents of `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "domain.tld" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/domain.tld.db";
      };**
```

`dig -x www.domain.tld` response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> -x www.domain.tld
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 34575
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tld.domain.www.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
in-addr.arpa.           3600    IN      SOA     b.in-addr-servers.arpa. nstld.iana.org. 2015072757 1800 900 604800 3600

;; Query time: 1233 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 21 16:20:04 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

Comment: There is a good chance that the Google servers look at the `Host:` header your browser sends, and if it says anything besides `google.com` or any of their other domains, it responds with an error.  I would testing your bind setup using `nslookup` or `dig`, not the web browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll updated my question with the output of  `dig`. So is my goal impossible with Google as the target, or is there a more bullet proof way to accomplish what I'm trying to?

Comment: You'd need a proxy or redirect.

Comment: Can that be done with a DNS server like `bind`? Or do I need a web server like Apache? (I'd have thought the latter would be limited to a particular port).

Comment: And any pointers to the directive I need to look up in the manual would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the CNAME record to www.google.com was correct in the question but I think I didn't have a `.` suffix in my actual file on my server. So the short answer is:

> CNAME record targets should have a `.` suffix.

There will be other issues with trying to navigate to places like google.com, but this should fix the domain alias part.